# Why comparing an Integer object with a primitive int throws null pointer exception when the Integer object is null in Java

Tags: java, design-decisions

Why does the code below throw null pointer exception? I would expect the equivalence to be simply false. Can someone explain what happens under the hood and the reason for this design decision?

```
Integer i = null;
System.out.println(i == 10);  // Throws a null pointer exception
```

Comment: You might want to some research into "auto boxing" in Java

Comment: Well, `Integer` is just an object.  Any object reference can throw NPE in Java: `Object i = null; System.out.println( i == 10 );`

Comment: @MadProgrammer ,  how would you explain the NPE given that  

    System.err.println(i == new Integer(10));

prints false  ?

Comment: @DavidSoroko Read the duplicate link `Integer == Integer` is now comparing object references (as apposed to `int == int` which will compare primitive values), since they aren't the same reference, the comparison is `false`

Comment: Well yes, and regarding  the OPs question...

Comment: As the relevant links in the referenced answer is broken, have  a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1

The NPE happens due to unboxing of i